# How to display a block in twig (D8)

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

I read the other similar questions, but it didn't work.

I created a block in a region and I want to display that same block on my custom page (inside the twig).

I'm using this code to load the block:

```
$block = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('block')->load('block_id');
$block_content =  \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block')->view($block);
```

and I'm trying to build it like this:

```
$build['page'] = array(
      '#type' => 'inline_template',
      '#template' => $template,
      '#form' => $block_content,
);
return $build;
```

My twig file is like this:

```
<section>
  <tbody>
    <div>{{ form }}</div>
  </tbody>
</section>
```

But nothing is displayed...
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the `form` variable available in the Twig template you need to supply a context like follows.

```
$build['page'] = [
  '#type' => 'inline_template',
  '#template' => $template,
  '#context' => ['form' => $block_content],
];
```

Generally, I would recommend using custom `#theme` hook instead of an inline template.

Another way to render block within a template is using [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module.

```
{{ drupal_entity('block', 'block_id') }}
```